# sign and saturation functions with drake variables

Tags: drake

I'm wondering if there are equivalents to numpy.sign() and numpy.clip() functions that can work with drake variables? For example the following code gives me the error:

```
from pydrake.all import Variable
q = Variable('q')
u = 1 + np.sign(q) # Doesn't work
u = 1 + np.clip(q, -1, 1) # Doesn't work
# Pass u into the dynamics of a SymbolicVectorSystem
```

> RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`. If you are trying to make a map with `Variable`, `Expression`, or `Polynomial` as keys (and then access the map in Python), please use pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict`.

Which I guess means numpy is doing some checks on `q` that is leading to this error? And perhaps if there is an alternate Drake function that works on `Formula`s this wouldn't happen?

I'm thinking a solution would be to use a [port switch](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_port_switch.html) to implement the sign function, and [saturation](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_saturation.html) to implement saturation and compose blocks to feed into SymbolicVectorSystem. I was just wondering if there was something even simpler I was missing, and if this is the best way.

Context: I'm playing around with robust control and would like to implement dynamics and controllers that use the sign and saturation functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have `min`, `max`, and `if_then_else`, which should do the trick.

```
from pydrake.all import Variable, if_then_else, min, max
q = Variable('q')
#u = np.sign(q) # Doesn't work, but we can do
u = if_then_else(q > 0, 1, if_then_else(q < 0, -1, 0))

# u = np.clip(q, -1, 1) # Doesn't work, but we can do
u = min(max(q, -1), 1)
```

We actually also have `clamp` in c++, but somehow didn't add the python binding for that more recent addition.  It would be easy enough to add.

Comment: I should also mention that Drake's lyapunov tools won't support these out of the box; but you can implement this sort of logic using the S-procedure we discussed in class last week!

Comment: If we decide to add clamp in pydrake (as sugar for min∘max), I'd probably suggest naming it `clip` to match what numpy calls it.